# How to add wordpress slug manually in php file?

Tags: php, seo, google-search

When i search for a specific page on the web for my website it shows the index file on all the searches e.g. www.website.com/ whereas it should show www.website.com/pageone.php

On wordpress this is called a slug, how can i replicated this similar to how you do the description in meta tags?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which allows you to map arbitrary URLs to your internal PHP URL structure (e.g. `example.com/about` to `index.php?page=about`).

It's the same technique as used by wordpress.